# Fetch last 4 quarter's and respective timestamps in epoch format in javaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking for javascript snippet that returns object which contains current quarter epoch timestamp and timestamp for past 4 quarters also it should be dynamic to the current quarter

return should be something like:

```
{ Q4 - 2019: 
   { startTime: "",
     endTime: ""  },
 Q3 - 2019: 
   { startTime: "",
     endTime: ""  },
 Q2 - 2019: 
   { startTime: "",
     endTime: ""  },
 Q1 - 2019: 
   { startTime: "",
     endTime: ""  },
 Q4 - 2018: 
   { startTime: "",
     endTime: ""  },
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which is the part that's stumping you? What is the format of the timestamps? In general contributors will help with a problem you're facing, but we don't like to complete the entire assignment.

Comment: part of identifying the timestamps and the format will be epoch